# Perl script that parses CSV file excluding the contents enclosed in []

Tags: perl, csv

Hi there I am struggling with perl script that parses a an eight column CSV line into another CSV line using the split command. But i want to exclude all the text enclosed by square brackets []. The line looks like :

```
128.39.120.51,0,49788,6,SYN,[8192:127:1:52:M1460,N,W2,N,N,S:.:Windows:XP/2000 (RFC1323+, w+, tstamp-):link:ethernet/modem],1,1399385680
```

I used the following script but when i print $fields[7] it gives me N. one of the fields inside [] above.but by print "$fields[7]" i want it to be **1399385680** which is the last field in the above     line. the script i tried was.

```
while (my $line = <LOG>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @fields=grep { !/^[\[.*\]]$/ } split ",", $line;
    my $timestamp=$fields[7];
    print "$fields[7]";
}
```

Thanks for your time. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: At the very least, your grep is throwing away fields that consist of a single character (the re looks like `^[...]$` (I don't really care what the `...` amounts to).

Answer (score 1):

Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of EVERY perl script.

Your "csv" file isn't proper csv.  So the only thing I can suggest is to remove the contents in the brackets before you split:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    s/\[.*?\]//g;
    my @fields = split ',', $_;
    my $timestamp = $fields[7];
    print "$timestamp\n";
}
__DATA__
128.39.120.51,0,49788,6,SYN,[8192:127:1:52:M1460,N,W2,N,N,S:.:Windows:XP/2000 (RFC1323+, w+, tstamp-):link:ethernet/modem],1,1399385680
```

Outputs:

```
1399385680
```

Obviously it is possible to also capture the contents of the bracketed fields, but you didn't say that was a requirement or goal.

**Update**

If you want to capture the bracket delimited field, one method would be to use a regex for capturing instead.

Note, this current regex requires that each field has a value.

```
chomp;
my @fields = $_ =~ /(\[.*?\]|[^,]+)(?:,|$)/g;
my $timestamp = $fields[7];
print "$timestamp";
```

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo Miller, But that was not the problem infact. when I use split, it is considering the whole line, not skipping the contents under the square brackets. I want to ignore the whole content of the square bracket.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply but how do I include the contents inside the square brackets if i want to include them in the CSV line as one field of the eight column CSV line.?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to actually *ignore* the text between square brackets, you might as well get rid of it:

```
while ( my $line = <LOG> ) {
  chomp $line;
  $line =~ s,\[.*?\],,; # Delete all text between square brackets
  my @fields = split ",", $line;
  my $timestamp = $fields[7];
  print $fields[7], "\n";
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is working well by deleting the contents inside []. and then splitting the rest line.